# How to import existing keycloak realm from my local directory when deploying keycloak into kinD kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I am new to kubernetes and kinD. I am using kinD to deploy keycloak locally using yaml.

Below is the yml file I am using.

How can I import an existing realm JSON when deploying using below yml.

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: jboss/keycloak:9.0.0
          env:
            - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
              value: "admin"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
              value: "admin"
            - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
              value: "true"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: https
              containerPort: 8443
```

Comment: Do you mean to get the same data but in JSON format? If yes you can try to use `kubectl get deployment keycloak -o JSON`

Comment: I meant to import existing realm and users into Keycloak